# Selecting one row is checking the mark of another row

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm getting a weird problem with table view in iOS. In the table, when I click on a row, I want a checkmark to be displayed, it is working very fine with the code below:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }else{
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

Right now, my table has 11 rows. When I click on the 1st row, the checkmark appears for the 1st row (this is good) but it also appears for the 10th row. When I click on the 2nd row, the 2nd(this is good) and the 11th appears.

Does anyone has an idea about this issue?

Comment: You should never keep the selected state in the table cell since they are reused. You should keep the selected state in the obejct filling the table view cell.

Comment: Or just enable multiple selections on the table view and let it do it all for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this...

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

Then when you need to get all the selected rows...

```
NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```

This array will contain all the rows with the checkmarks on them.

No need to do anything in code yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For the same thing what you are trying to do, I implemented it in following way -

**Declare a NSIndexPath Variable in AppDelegate or in local file.**

```
if (Appdelegate.selectedIndexPath == (id)[NSNull null]) {
     NSLog(@"null");

     Appdelegate.selectedWebsiteIndex=indexPath;
     UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

 }else{

     UITableViewCell *cell1 = [aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: Appdelegate.selectedIndexPath];
     cell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

     Appdelegate.selectedIndexPath =indexPath;
     UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

 }
```

Hope This helps you..